# Action event on a JButton matrix

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I can't handle the event in my matrix of JButtons. I need to figure out which button is pressed, then change an objects color to match the button.

I am currently using this code:

```
private class matrixButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JButton btn = (JButton) (e.getSource());
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixBouton.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixBouton[i].length; j++)
            {
                btn.equals(matrixBouton[i][j]);
                if (btn.getBackground() == COLOR_NEUTRAL)
                {
                    btn.setBackground(COLOR_PLAYER);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? And why go through the for loops? Why not just act on the `getSource()` JButton?

Comment: Your original post was amazingly hard to comprehend, and I have attempted to edit it for that. SO is a professional site; please use grammar as if this were your workplace (assuming you don't work at McDonald's).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of looping through all `JButtons` you simply trace the button using `evt.getSource()`. This will return you the reference to the actual button pressed. And then you can perform as you wish. 
You can use following simplified code indeed:

```
private class matrixButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JButton btn = (JButton) (e.getSource());
        if (btn.getBackground() == COLOR_NEUTRAL)
         {
            btn.setBackground(COLOR_PLAYER);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you could do is store the coordinates inside the `ActionListener`:

```
private class matrixButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    private int i;
    private int j;

    public matrixButtonListener (int i, int j)
    {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //this gives you the button on which you pressed
        JButton pressedButton = matrixBouton[this.i][this.j];

        if (pressedButton.getBackground() == COLOR_NEUTRAL)
        {
            pressedButton.setBackground(COLOR_PLAYER);
        }
    }
}
```

You set each Listener like this:

```
matrixBouton[i][j].addActionListener (new matrixButtonListener (i, j));
```

There will be `i x j` instances of the Listener created. Usually this isn't a big deal, unless `i x j` is really big (3 digits or 4 digits big).

Comment: my dam teacher wants us to store the button pressed in that Jbutton btn, i would do it differently too but i cant..., i HAVE to use the jbutton :(

Comment: @Pierre-lucG. You have to be more specific. In the meantime, try using `equals` to compare those colors... 'cause `==` is probably wrong...